# Windows Server 2012 Best Practices Analyzer - file services

Tags: windows-server-2012

I ran Windows Server 2012 Best Practices Analyzer and it has reported - The file services role service is not installed.

Should I worry? What is it required for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file server role enables features related to advanced quota management, indexing, and so on.  You don't technically need it to simply share a folders, but if the server is acting primarily as a file server, you might want to consider enabling that role, since you might want to use some of the additional features.